# Book about explanation of 4th dimension using analogy with 2d object interacting with 3d

Tags: reference-request, 3d, hyperspace

I'm searching for a book about the explanation of 4th and higher dimensions using an analogy with 2d space creatures (flatland) with 3d dimension (as humans).

I need to to add and update Polish Wikipedia article "Płaszczak" which is a creature that live in 2d space. I know about Flatland but I don't think it use 3d objects. I need a book that shows that those creatures are useful in math to explain 4th dimension.

I was asking chatGPT and he suggested that it may be explained in the Hyperspace book by Michio Kaku. I've already ordered that book - Polish translation - in hope there will be some reference to 2d creatures.

I remember reading some book that explained that 3d person can get things from a closed box (rectangle) in 2d space, the same with 4th dimension people that could get into a closed room that has no windows or doors. The problem is that I don't know which book it was.

Do you know any book that can be used as a reference to the Flatland creature used to explain 4th dimension and that a mental model like this is useful in Math?

Comment: "The shape of space" is a nice book with many pictures

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphereland  by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dionys_Burger